# Why do new processes default to priority "Very High"?

Tags: process, nice

What service or job is causing this to happen? If I run the *System Monitor* I see that some processes for newly installed applications default to *Very High*.

Here is an example, it includes some programs that I understand might be set to very high, but also includes a program I never use "soffice" which is Open Office. It's set to "Very High" but I never use it and I certainly never set it to be high priority.

[image]

Comment: Services such as `pulseaudio` do need higher priority than others, likely this is hard-coded into them. What exactly is the issue you're having ?

Comment: I updated my post with some examples and a screenshot.

Comment: hmm, that is abnormal. Look into  /etc/security/limits.conf file, see if priority is set to very high for your user there.

Comment: There's definitely an issue with his priority.